# how to count lines of a paragraph in java?

Tags: java, itext

I have developed a program and I created a column and inserted a paragraph into that column.

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
 Font font = new Font(bfBold.createFont());
 //float maxFontSize=10;
 font.setSize(10);
 Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a long paragraph that doesn't fit the width we defined for the simple column of the ColumnText object, so it will be distributed over several lines (and we don't know in advance how many).",font);
 p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    //LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader());
    ct.setSimpleColumn(100f, 550f, 395f, 150f);

    ct.addElement(p);
    ct.go();
```

I have inserted paragraph into `ct(column text)`.

So now I wanted to count lines of this paragraph.
So how can I do that?

I used itext api. I'm generating a pdf here.

Comment: swing? javafx? itext?

Comment: We have no idea what `ColumnText` and `Paragraph` are.  Are they your own classes?  What do they look like?  We don't have nearly enough info to help you.

Comment: please add import statement to clearify that these classes that you used belongs to what ???

Comment: i used itext... i'm generating a pdf file..

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-row-count-multiline-field

Answer (score 2):

After the content of the `ColumnText` is rendered (either for real, or in simulation mode), you can use the [getLinesWritten()](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#getLinesWritten--) method to get the number of lines that were written.

The link I used points at the iText API documentation. You'll also find this information in the FAQ: [How to get the rendered dimensions of text?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-rendered-dimensions-text) and in the examples of the "iText in Action" book; see the [MovieColumns1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3#158-moviecolumns1.java) example.

I'm sorry for the "link-only" answer (which is usually not appreciated on StackOverflow), but the only line of code that is needed, is:

```
int lines = ct.getLinesWritten();
```

Comment: *I'm sorry for the "link-only" answer ... but the only line of code that is needed, is: ...* - so it's not a link-only answer after all! ;)